# centre horizontally within parent

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

On [this page](http://festivals.ie/show/44#headline) I show a list of artists appearing at a festival. The placement of the artist `<div>`s is controlled by [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (it was very difficult to get everything to lineup properly using CSS alone when there are a large number of artists and the artist `div`s are different heights).

Anyway, I would like to centre the artist divs within their parent container so that there's an equal amount of white space to the left and right of the artists, as illustrated below.

[image]

I've tried all the obvious things like:

```
margin: 0 auto
text-align: center
```

But no luck so far....

Comment: try bootstrap, I attached an answer bellow it will make your life so much easier :)

Comment: @DoryZidon I'm already using bootstrap, but for this content which is of variable height/width, the grid doesn't work well

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using something like a bootstrap grid? 
It will make your life so much easier.

you just define a container and bootstrap grid will do all the heavy lifting for you.
include adjust to various devices :)

```
<!-- simple three column display that will take seconds to create -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">/div>
    <div class="span4">/div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
 </div>
```

[Bootstrap Grid from Twitter Guide](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

[Bootstrap Text Tutorial](http://www.revillwebdesign.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/)

[Bootstrap Video Tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-grid/)

Comment: I'm already using Bootstrap, however in this particular case the artist `div`s can all be of different heights and widths, so a grid doesn't really work

Answer (score 1):

The PARENT must have

```
text-align:center; width:abc;
```

and a certain width. Then the child should have

```
margin:auto; text-align:left; width:xyz;
```

Example:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <div style="width:50%; text-align:left; background:red; margin:auto;">
        This will do it just right
    </div>
</div>
```

if this does not work, you should really check if something else influences the behavior!